# Sending HTTP Post Requests work in Fiddler but not in Python

Tags: python, api, http, python-2.7, post

I am sending several post requests in Fiddler2 to check my site to make sure it is working properly. However, when I automate in Python to simulate this over several hours (I really don't want to spend 7 hours hitting space!).

This works in fiddler. I can create the account and perform related API commands. However in Python, nothing happens with this code:

```
def main():
    import socket
    from time import sleep
    x = raw_input("Points: ")
    x = int(x)
    x = int(x/150)
    for y in range(x):
        new = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        new.connect(('example.com', 80))
        mydata ="""POST http://www.example.com/api/site/register/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 191
X-NewRelic-ID: UAIFVlNXGwEFV1hXAwY=
Origin: http://www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-CSRFToken: CEC9EzYaQOGBdO9HGPVVt3Fg66SVWVXg
DNT: 1
Referer: http://www.example.com/signup
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8
Cookie: sessionid=sessionid; sb-closed=true; arp_scroll_position=600; csrftoken=2u92jo23g929gj2; __utma=912.1.1.2.5.; __utmb=9139i91; __utmc=2019199; __utmz=260270731.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)

username=user&password=password&moredata=here """
        new.send(mydata.encode('hex'))
        print "Sent", y, "of", x
        sleep(1)
    print "Sent all!"
    print "restarting"
    main()
main()
```

I know I could use `While True`, but I intend to add more functions later to test more sites.

Why does this program not do anything to the API, when Fiddler2 can? I know it is my program, as I can send the exact same packet in fiddler (obviously pointing to the right place) and it works.

PS - If anyone does fix this, as its probably something really obvious, please can you only use modules that are bundled with Python. I cannot install modules from other places. Thanks!

Comment: I can't see how `mydata` is **exactly** the same as the HTTP request you've made above. You don't send any headers (including `POST http://www.example.com/api/site/register/ HTTP/1.1`). Perhaps you should write exactly what you put in `mydata`. Plus why do you `.encode('hex')` data? HTTP is a raw string. Finally: you should use some high level library (instead of low level sockets) like this one: http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html

Comment: Mydata is the packet above, just that it breaks formatting for some reason if I include it in the code, so I used a separate chunk. Also, because the site I used said to encode it as HEX. Is this the problem?

Comment: @freakish. I saved the packet above as a multi-line variable. Fixed it! :D

Comment: Good. Much better. Now what you don't know is how HTTP requests are made. I'll answer your question soon.

Comment: Thanks :D   Would whoever has downvoted please explain why. I am open to criticism, as long as its constuctive, so I can write better questions next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP requests are not as easy as you think they are. First of all this is wrong:

```
"""POST http://www.example.com/api/site/register/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
...
"""
```

**Each line** in HTTP request has to end with CRLF (in Python with `\r\n`), i.e. it should be:

```
"""POST http://www.example.com/api/site/register/ HTTP/1.1\r
Host: www.example.com\r
Connection: keep-alive\r
...
"""
```

**Note**: LF = line feed = `\n` is there implicitly. Also you didn't see CR in your fiddler, because it's a white-space. But it has to be there (simple copy-paste won't work).

Also HTTP specifies that after headers there has to be CRLF as well. I.e. your entire request should be:

```
    mydata = """POST http://www.example.com/api/site/register/ HTTP/1.1\r
Host: www.example.com\r
Connection: keep-alive\r
Content-Length: 191\r
X-NewRelic-ID: UAIFVlNXGwEFV1hXAwY=\r
Origin: http://www.example.com\r
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36\r
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01\r
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r
X-CSRFToken: CEC9EzYaQOGBdO9HGPVVt3Fg66SVWVXg\r
DNT: 1\r
Referer: http://www.example.com/signup\r
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8\r
Cookie: sessionid=sessionid; sb-closed=true; arp_scroll_position=600; csrftoken=2u92jo23g929gj2; __utma=912.1.1.2.5.; __utmb=9139i91; __utmc=2019199; __utmz=260270731.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)\r
\r
username=user&password=password&moredata=here"""
```

**Warning**: it should be exactly as I've written. There can't be any spaces in front of each line, i.e. this:

```
    mydata = """POST http://www.example.com/api/site/register/ HTTP/1.1\r
    Host: www.example.com\r
    Connection: keep-alive\r
    ...
"""
```

is wrong.

**Side note**: you can move `mydata` to the top, outside of the loop. Unimportant optimization but makes your code cleaner.

Now you've said that the site you are using wants you to hex-encode HTTP request? It's hard for me to believe that (HTTP is a raw string by definition). Don't do that (and ask them to specify what exactly this hex-encoding means). Possibly they've meant that the URL should be hex-encoded (since it is the only hex-encoding that is actually used in HTTP)? In your case there is nothing to encode so don't worry about it. Just remove the `.encode('hex')` line.

Also `Content-Length` header is messed up. It should be the actual length of the content. So if for example body is `username=user&password=password&moredata=here` then it should be `Content-Length: 45`.

Next thing is that the server might not allow you making multiple requests without getting a response. You should use `new.recv(b)` where `b` is a number of bytes you want to read. But how many you should read? Well this might be problematic and that's where `Content-Length` header comes in. First you have to read headers (i.e. read until you read `\r\n\r\n` which means the end of headers) and then you have to read the body (based on `Content-Length` header). As you can see things are becoming messy (see: final section of my answer).

There are probably more issues with your code. For example `X-CSRFToken` suggests that the site uses CSRF prevention mechanism. In that case your request might not work at all (you have to get the value of `X-CSRFToken` header from the server).

**Finally**: don't use sockets directly. Httplib (http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) is a great (and built-in) library for making HTTP requests which will deal with all the funky and tricky HTTP stuff for you. Your code for example may look like this:

```
import httplib

headers = {
    "Host": "www.example.com",
    "X-NewRelic-ID": "UAIFVlNXGwEFV1hXAwY=",
    "Origin": "http://www.example.com",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "X-CSRFToken": "CEC9EzYaQOGBdO9HGPVVt3Fg66SVWVXg",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Referer": "http://www.example.com/signup",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.8",
    "Cookie": "sessionid=sessionid; sb-closed=true; arp_scroll_position=600; csrftoken=2u92jo23g929gj2; __utma=912.1.1.2.5.; __utmb=9139i91; __utmc=2019199; __utmz=260270731.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)"
}

body = "username=user&password=password&moredata=here"

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("example.com")
conn.request("POST", "http://www.example.com/api/site/register/", body, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
```

Note that you don't need to specify `Content-Length` header.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One thing that I have no idea about is how Memrise got in there! My mistake - edited the question slightly. Thanks for the great and well explained answer. +1 to you :)

Comment: I don't intend to cause any offence, but to save time for you I changed the host manually. If this causes any problems then of course I will revert it :)

Comment: I see. I need to save it in a dictionary! It all makes sense now - thanks :D

Comment: use an even higher level library,l like `urllib2` or `requests`.